# how to bind two events to an element in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am novice to Knockout.js.

I have a code snippet, which basically opens a modal on click of an image button. For some reason it is not working on key press.

Here is the initial code:

```
<div class="text-center tooltip-lg">
    <a class="tooltip-container" tabindex="0">
        <i class="icon icon-pencil dynamic-icon tooltip_trigger" title="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assessment_type_modal" data-placement="top" data-bind="click: $root.opt.openModalForEdit"></i></a></div>
```

Since it was missing keypress or keyup event, I made the below changes.

```
<div class="text-center tooltip-lg">
    <a class="tooltip-container" tabindex="0">
        <i class="icon icon-pencil dynamic-icon tooltip_trigger" title="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assessment_type_modal" data-placement="top" data-bind="event: { click: $root.opt.openModalForEdit, keypress: $root.opt.openModalForEdit }" ></i></a></div>
```

The action is not triggered by the keypress. I tried keyup as well ( as mentioned in some of the questions in stackoverflow. ), that didn't work too.

```
The Model looks like this: 

viewModel.opt = {
    openModalForNew: function () {
        // Some code
    },
    openModalForEdit: function (assessmentType) {
        // Some code
    },
    saveModal: function () {
        // Some code
    },
    removeAsmtType: removeAsmtType
};
```

Update: The action is recognized but don't know why the event is not triggered.
        when I run the below test case, the test is printed on console everytime I hover the mouse over that  tag.

```
<div class="text-center tooltip-lg">
    <a class="tooltip-container" tabindex="0">
        <i class="icon icon-pencil dynamic-icon tooltip_trigger" title="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assessment_type_modal" data-placement="top" data-bind="event: { click: $root.opt.openModalForEdit, 'mouseover' : function () { console.log('TEST'); return true; }" ></i></a></div>
```

Can any one suggest what is that I am doing wrong. There are no errors that are shown in the browser console as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a snippet or fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` event is triggered on the element that has focus, i.e.: an element that has the `tabindex` (or even `contenteditable`) attribute or supports it automatically (like any `<input>` element).

You can fix your issue by moving the `event: { keypress: ... }` binding to your `<a>` element that has `tabindex=0`.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  onPress: function(d, e) {
    console.log("keypress on node", e.target.nodeName);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Tap the text and press a key. The console will log the element that has the keypress event</p>
<a tabindex="0" data-bind="event: { 
  keypress: onPress
}">

  <i data-bind="event: {
    keypress: onPress
  }">some text</i>
</a>
```

Comment: I am facing an issue with implementing your solution. The attributes on the <i> tag are used by the Javascript library knockout.js to display a modal dialog window when the user clicks the "Edit" pencil icon. How can I solve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideally, the values of any attributes in the DOM are already in your underlying *viewmodel*. If you need a quick fix, you could use `e.target.querySelector("i")` to select the element, but I wouldn't recommend it.